# Is the k-clique problem NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, complexity-classes

In this Wikipedia article about the [Clique problem in graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) it states in the beginning that the problem of finding a clique of size K, in a graph G is NP-complete:

> Cliques have also been studied in computer science: finding whether there is a clique of a given size in a graph (the clique problem) is NP-complete, but despite this hardness result many algorithms for finding cliques have been studied.

But in this other Wikipedia article about the [Clique problem in CS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem)
 it says it is solving the problem for a fixed size k is a problem in P, it can be brute forced in polynomial time.

> A brute force algorithm to test whether a graph G contains a k-vertex clique, and to find any such clique that it contains, is to examine each subgraph with at least k vertices and check to see whether it forms a clique. This algorithm takes time O(n^k k^2): there are O(n^k) subgraphs to check, each of which has O(k^2) edges whose presence in G needs to be checked. Thus, the problem may be solved in polynomial time whenever k is a fixed constant. When k is part of the input to the problem, however, the time is exponential.

Is there something I am missing here? Maybe a difference in the wording of the problem? And what does the last sentence mean, that "When k is part of the input to the problem, however, the time is exponential."? Why is there a difference when the k is part of the input to the problem?

My idea is that to find a clique of size k in a graph G, is that we first choose a subset of size k of nodes from G, and test wether they are all related to the other k nodes, which can be done in constant time. And repeat this until we have a clique of size k. The number of sets of k nodes we can choose from G is n! / k!*(n-k)!.

Comment: The NP-completeness of a problem depends on what you consider as an input. Because a problem is in $\mathcal{P}$ if there is a polynomial algorithm to decide it. If $K$ is a constant (not an input), the algorithm is polynomial in $n$. If $k$ is a part of the input, then the algorithm is exponential in $k$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just elaborating what @Lamine pointed out : When $k$ is part of the input, $k$ can be as large as $\frac{n}{2}$, in which case the number of potential clique sets are $\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}}$ which is at least $\left( \frac{n}{\frac{n}{2}} \right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$. Hence your naive algorithm would take time $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ which is clearly exponential in input length $|x|+|k|=n+\log n$. The parameterized version $G(n,k)$ where we are looking for $k$-cliques in an $n$-vertex graph captures the hardness of the problem in its most generalized form because $k$ is part of the input. Hence a poly-time algorithm for $G(n,k)$ would also imply a poly-time algorithm for any specific $k$.