# Why is Minimum $k$-cut NP hard when $k$ is specified as part of the input?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, approximation

As you know a set of edges whose removal leaves $k$ connected components is called a $k$-cut. The minimum  $k$-cut problem asks for a minimum weight $k$-cut.

For $k=2$ this problem is **P**.

*Vazirani* in his [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=EILqAmzKgYIC&hl=en) says for any fixed $k$ when $3 \le k$ it is **NP-hard** and When $k$ is specified as part of the input this problem is also **NP-hard**.

I would like to know what difference does it make when $k$ is specified as part of the input? and why is it **NP-hard** in this case?

Comment: I already saw that before. I guess this is in contradiction with Vazirani book. But I  will take care of that when I figure out why for not specified $k$ it is **NP-hard** :)

Answer (score 4):

First, be careful what Vazirani actually says. On page 38, it is written that:

> "The minimum $k$-cut problem is polynomial time solvable for fixed $k$; however, it is **NP**-hard if $k$ is specified as part of the input."

(In particular, the claim you make about being NP-hard for any fixed $k \geq 3$ holds for a different problem, namely *minimum weight multiway cut*). Indeed, [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut) this is the case as well: for any fixed $k$, you can solve the minimum $k$-cut problem in $O(n^{k^2})$ time. In other words, when $k$ is fixed, you have polynomially many ways of removing $k$ edges. So why does it matter if something is part of the input or fixed then?

When $k$ is fixed, it is *not* part of the input. The problem is this:

> (Minimum $k$-cut.) *Input:* A graph $G$. *Question:* Is there a $k$-cut?

So the problem is defined for every fixed value of $k$. We have minimum 2-cut, minimum 3-cut, minimum 4-cut, and so on. In contrast, the problem could be this:

> (Minimum cut.) *Input:* A graph $G$, an integer $k$. *Question:* Is there a $k$-cut?

Now, it is possible for $k$ to depend crucially on the size of the graph. This way a naive brute-force won't give you a polynomial time algorithm. Another example is given [in this question of ours](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6847/472) in the context of finding cliques.

Comment: Being $k \geq 3$ doesn't mean that $k$ is fixed?

Comment: @Noone Being $k \geq 3$ is NP-hard, then this means that k is NP-hard for fixed k. This follows that it is NP-hard for k equal n. Now, Vizirnai's make this difference of the two; because usually to prove hardness for fixed is different than prove hardness for any any k; and this is one way to show Strongly NP-hard. I suggest reading Garey and Johnson textbook